# Leaflet routing machine not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, cordova, leaflet

I've been doing mobile app that should navigate user to specific points. I've been using leaflet routing machine to do this and everything works fine in browser, but after deploying it to phone, whole navigation disappears.

This one is in browser:
[image: This is how it looks in browser]

This one is on phone:
[image: This is how it looks on phone]

Have anyone had the same issue?

Comment: Try to inspect your device's console and post if you find some error

Comment: there is a lot of notifications, but I havent found any error that would matter...

Comment: The console print the same result from browser and mobile web view? If there are some differences i think that this information is a good startpoint to this error analysis

Comment: I tried with weinre now, and it seems that request for url that starts with two slashes is pending and can't be done on phonegap!

Answer (score 3):

So the problem was that routing machine was sending request to `//router.project-osrm.org/viaroute` and I had to change it to `http://router.project-osrm.org/viaroute`